# обойти каждую группировку в Pandas циклом

Tags: python, pandas

Пытаюсь обойти каждую группировку ниже циклом но не получается,может кто подскажет в чем проблема?Ниже цикл он вываливает ошибку ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2),понятно что колонок более двух их 7 но с 1 или 2 колонками туже ошибку почему то выдает

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Provider', 'Name', 'Sku', 'Price','Image']).sum() //сгруппировал все
for name, group in grouped://пытаюсь отобрать каждую группировку в отдельности
    print("Группа:")
    print(name)  # Вывод ключей группировки
    print(group)  # Вывод данных для данной группы
    print("\n")
```

Например: Есть сгрупированные данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Код" это код товара для группировки. Так вот я хочу циклом отбирать каждую отдельную группировку чтоб потом из группировки вытаскивать каждое значение для записи в файл. Проблема отобрать каждую группировку. Остальное знаю как сделать .То есть первый отбор в цикле будет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ну и так далее

Comment: Добавьте  минимальный пример данных, и что должно получиться. Может вопрос будет исчерпан.

Comment: Удалите `.sum()`

Comment: Зачем удалять Sum если мне нужен итог по колонкам которые содержат цифры @Алексей Р

Comment: Указал пример в тексте вопроса @Oopss

Comment: По вашему совету для теста удалил Sum и теперь выше упомянутым циклом получаю такую картину Группа: ВС   Колготки    100    100      1                                                                                              
Группа: Рубашка     50     100      2                                                                                                                                  Группа:  Штаны       150    300      2                                                                                                  
Но ведь Группа ВС одна а не три    @Алексей Р

Comment: Рекомендую все-таки прислушаться к советам и разместить в вопросе: пример фрейма и целевой вид. Иначе очень сложно сложить картинку из мыслей вслух.

Comment: Фрейм нужно разместить в текстовом виде, а не картинкой, поскольку картинку сложно использовать в коде

Comment: @Sergey у вас в колонке "код" незаполненные значения и имена колонок в примере данных не совпадает с именами колонок в программе.

Comment: Расползается текст в строку, не удобно читать .столбиками не получается @Алексей Р

Comment: Вы не хотите просто выводить по условиям т.е. в колонке код у вас есть некое значение. Ну и пройти перебором:
df_1 = df[df['Код'] == 'ВС' ]это для одного случая, а вам  надо будет перебать по всем так. Просто не ясно, что далее вы делаете, может ещё можно упростить.